# Previews for audio e-commerce site

Tags: magento, audio

Is there a way to do previews for audio files in the base, Magento Community Edition? I see the place to put the "sample" files under "Downloadable information" section on my product. I attached an .MP3 as the sample, in this case, and it won't play. If alternatively, I try to download the file locally and then play it, instead of the 400K+ file, I just get a 4K file of garbled nothing, and it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior you've described sounds as though it may be an issue with Magento (in which case you may want to inquire at the [Magento user forum](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards) or file a bug report).

Whether or not Magento supports native MP3 sample streaming, your site's users can play the sample MP3 files in the audio player of their choice (without an [embedded Flash player](http://www.webdesignbooth.com/10-easy-to-implement-flash-based-mp3-players-for-your-website/) or reliance on [HTML5](http://html5doctor.com/native-audio-in-the-browser/)) if you create [M3U files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U) which point to the respective URLs of the uploaded samples.

For example, if you have a sample file named "test.mp3", you would want to upload that file to a location like `http://example.com/samples/test.mp3` and create an M3U file which references that URL:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:-1,http://example.com/samples/test.mp3
http://example.com/samples/test.mp3
```

Users who download the M3U file will be prompted (if they have a compatible audio player installed) to open the M3U file and stream the `http://example.com/samples/test.mp3` sample in their audio player.

Comment: This is a really cool solution. I think I'm going to wind up modifying the Magento product page so I can get an embedded player (after thinking it over, that's more akin to the functionality I'm looking for), but you've definitely answered my question. Thanks!